# scala or java library that will read .ssh/config

Tags: java, scala, ssh, ammonite

I have an entry in my `.ssh/config` file that looks like:

Host ip-172-16-*

```
ProxyCommand ssh jeff@jumpdev.example.org nc %h %p
User ubuntu
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws
StrictHostKeyChecking no
ForwardAgent yes
```

As most know this will allow me to run:
`ssh ip-172-16-2-108.ec2.internal` and I drop onto the private server, as the default user for Ubuntu EC2 instances - ubuntu.  I'm looking to take some specific actions on create.

Ultimately what i am looking for is the same functionality with either `scala-ssh`, `jassh` or directly from `jsch`

I'm not asking for anyone to suggest a library, just how/if this functionality is supported.  With `jassh`, i've attempted with the Proxy options with no luck.

Ultimately i could shell out directly to ssh, but even with `ammonite`, it won't load the config if using `%('ssh, Symbol("ip-172-16-2-108.ec2.internal")`.  I thought that would use the base ssh, which would load the config and match, like bare ssh.  I could also set up my config not to use `nc`

This does sound like i'm asking for a library, so if it gets closed, so be it, but i've tried 4 directly and none, seem to completely support `.ssh/config`

TIA,
Jeff

Comment: So if you're not asking to suggest the library, what exactly is your question?

Comment: If one of these libraries can accommodate `.ssh/config` options, specifically `ProxyCommand`, i've just found out that `jsch` does not parse that option.  Even though it does support an openSSHOption parser, Which rules out likely all of them :( .  Mainly been banging my head against the wall...so i come here :)

Comment: this [library](https://github.com/cronn-de/ssh-proxy) looks appealing, am going to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I know there are other answers, but I found that by switching from `ProxyCommand` to `ProxyJump` in my `.ssh/config` allowed `ammonite` to work perfectly.  Also since all I need is a solution to this problem and am already using `ammonite`, it is a good match.

If others have other experiences, I think this is a good question to leave open, as we're talking about specific libraries which are all built off `Jcsh`.

FWIW, my `.ssh/config` now looks like:

```
Host ip-172-16-*
  ProxyJump jeff@jumpdev.example.org
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_aws
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  ForwardAgent yes
```

Hope this helps someone.